# Java applet silently fails to run on Firefox and Chromium

Tags: java, applet

I'm trying to test my first applet.  I've uploaded the jar file, and an index.html, as shown

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Naggregator</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<H3><HR WIDTH="100%">Applet HTML Page<HR WIDTH="100%"></H3>

<P>
<!--<APPLET  archive="Naggregator.jar" code="NewJApplet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>-->
<!--<APPLET codetype="application/java-archive" classid="java:NewJApplet.class" width=350 height=200></APPLET>-->
<!--<APPLET archive="Naggregator.jar" code="NewJApplet.class" width="350" height="200">Wot no Java</APPLET>-->
<table class="app">
<tr>
<td>
        <applet width="350" height="200" archive="Naggregator.jar" code="NewJApplet.class">You need to enable Java to run this.</applet>
        <param name="permissions" value="sandbox" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</P>

<HR WIDTH="100%"><FONT SIZE=-1><I>Generated by NetBeans IDE</I></FONT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I've added the URL to the exception site list (although I don't think it's a security problem), and applets from other sites work.

All I see is the message about needing Java.
The commented bits are the other things I've tried based on StackOverflow responses.

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) Validate that HTML (as being compatible with HTML 3.2 - the last version that supported the `applet` element) to see that it is incorrect.

Comment: 1) Because I want to. 2) See 1. 3) What?  Is that even English?